# Wie soll ich in einem Zug um Hilfe fragen?

Tags: conversation

Ich fahre allein mit dem Zug von Wien nach Budapest und brauche Hilfe mit meinem Gepäck. Mein Gepäck ist sehr groß. Wie soll ich auf Deutsch um Hilfe fragen?

Comment: In deinem Text waren mehrere Fehler. Klick [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/52573/revisions) um deine Version mir meiner zu vergleichen. Wenn du deine Frage auf Deutsch stellst, solltest du auch die Überschrift in dieser Sprache schreiben.

Answer (score 9):

Die Antwort von [Janka](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/52574/36160) ist m.E. inhaltlich vollständig.

Jedoch würde ich das "bitte" nicht an das Ende stellen, denn es klingt für mich persönlich nach "ups, Freundlichkeit vergessen" oder "nun mach schon".

Daher meine Antwort für die Frage:

> Entschuldigung, könnten Sie mir bitte mit meinem Gepäck helfen?

(Restliche Hinweise wie oben.)

Answer (score 7):

> Entschuldigung! Könnten Sie mir vielleicht mit meinem Gepäck helfen, bitte?

Das deckt im Prinzip alles ab, den Rest kannst du dann mit Handzeichen erklären. Und dann nicht vergessen:

> Ich danke Ihnen!
>
> Vielen, vielen Dank!
>
> Das hätte ich allein nicht geschafft.

Und immer lächeln …

Comment: Der letzte Punkt ist enorm wichtig. Die meisten sind sehr hilfsbereit, wenn man freundlich ist.